# Remove duplicate array from parent array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array, lumen

I want to remove duplicate entry from the following array. Any idea would me appreciated.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 31
        )

)
```

Array key [1] and [2] having duplicate array with same values. I want to remove this duplicate array and the output should be like this:
                                          **Expected Output Must be like this**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 14
            [key2] => 31
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi @webdev use  this $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));

Comment: oh thanx @Cyperghost